# PHPSpreadsheet export xls file with complex formulas

Tags: php, xls, phpspreadsheet

I am using a laravel package "Maatwebsite" to export my data into a xls format.
As my data are complex and requires some complex formula as well.
I need to ***CONCATENATE*** two cells using ***LOOKUP*** formula and the formula looks like this
`=IF(B10<>"",CONCATENATE(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:A10<>""),$A$2:A10),"_",B10),"")`
But the problem is when ever i try to export into the xls the xls file only contains static value but not with formula.

What is want is when ever there is a change in ***A10*** and ***B10*** it should reflect it in ***C10*** as well. But It doesn't .

My Code looks like this

```
 $formula = '=IF(B10<>"",CONCATENATE(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:A10<>""),$A$2:A10),"_",B10),"")';
$sheet->setCellValueExplicit("C10", $formula, DataType::TYPE_FORMULA);
```

$sheet is from "AfterSheet" events.

but when i try using simple formula like

```
$formula = '=SUM(A10,B10)';
$sheet->setCellValueExplicit("C10", $formula, DataType::TYPE_FORMULA);
```

It works perfectly as expected.

Comment: Have you made an Excel file directly yourself, and validated that this formula definitely works as intended, before trying to use it via PHP?

Comment: @ADyson yes this formula works perfectly when i try it manually in excel, spreadsheet and in ods.

Comment: Ok thanks. So when you look at the Excel file generated by PHP, which uses this formula, is there any difference between how the formula is output into the spreadsheet, compared to the one you made yourself? Are you saying it just contains the output of the formula, rather than the cell having a formula set on it? Or it just contains a string which shows the formula as text? It wasn't totally clear.

Comment: Actually, When PHP generates the Excel file it doesn't export the formula like "VLOOKUP","LOOKUP" etc but only the values.

Comment: So you just see a number in the field instead, you mean? What number do you see? From another cell? Or a calculated value?

Comment: Also can you confirm, are you trying to generate an XLSX file, or a legacy XLS?

Comment: @ADyson Ohh Thanks ! I just figured it out. It was because i was trying to export it in XLS. With XLSX it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work properly, you need to be generating an XLSX file, not a legacy XLS file.